# Can't combine different query sets and render them in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

So i have to render a table on html template which combines columns from 2 different base models. But the table doent seem to render well. Entries from other table are shown in different rows.

[here is the screenshot of the table that has rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1xh8.png)

-I used the chain method from ittertools for this purpose. Not sure where I messed up.

Models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics')
    dob = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)



class Placement(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    company = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    city = models.CharField( max_length=40)
    bond = models.CharField(  max_length=40)
    ctc = models.CharField( max_length=40)
```

my Views.py:

```
def mentorintern(request):
    table = Placement.objects.all()
    name_student = Profile.objects.all()
    in_table = list(chain(table, name_student))

    return render(request, 'mentorinternship.html', {'in_table': in_table })
```

HTML template used to render the table:

```
<table class="table align-items-center table-flush table-hover" id="dataTableHover">
                  <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name of Student</th>
                      <th>Company</th>
                      <th>Position</th>
                      <th>City</th>
                      <th>CTC</th>
                      <th>Bond</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                    {% for std in in_table %}
                    <tr>

                      <td>{{std.first_name}}</td>
                      <td>{{std.company}}</td>
                      <td>{{std.position}}</td>
                      <td>{{std.city}}</td>
                      <td>{{std.ctc}}</td>
                      <td>{{std.bond}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %} 


                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do can be achieved easier than combining two query sets. Since you have a OneToOneField of User, you can directly access user details like this: `{{std.student.first_name}}}` inside the for loop. Now if I understand what you want, you probably need a foreign key of Profile table in Placement table. This way you can access, the profile as `{{std.profile.first_name}}` and the user table as `{{std.profile.user.first_name}}`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked!!. I implemented a new attribute in Placement that holds the foreign key for Profile table.